# NullPoinerExcep. при открытии БД в классе без контекста

Tags: android, context

Пытаюсь подключится  к БД   в  классе описывающий данные для RecyclerView и получаю `NullPointerException`.  строке `SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase()`;

```
public class MenuItem {
    Context mContext;
    String category_name;

    public MenuItem(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSpinnerStrings() {
        ArrayList<String> arrayListForSpinner = new ArrayList<>();
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("my_table", new String[]{"col_category"}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String forSpinner;
            forSpinner = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COL_CATEGORY));
            arrayListForSpinner.add(forSpinner);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return arrayListForSpinner;
    }
}
```

Ошибка

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
at com.example.vadik.alfatest.SupportClasses.MenuItem.getSpinnerStrings(MenuItem.java:26)
at com.example.vadik.alfatest.dialogs.DialogAddWord.<init>(DialogAddWord.java:30)
at com.example.vadik.alfatest.activitys.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:141)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2882)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:421)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:188)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:103)
at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:202)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:761)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:947)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:155)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Код DialogFragment, идет вызов getSpinnerStrings();

```
public class DialogAddWord extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
    EditText etNAtive, etForeign;
    Spinner spinner;
    Button btnSave, btnDone;
    AddWordInterface addWordInterface;
    MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList4spinnerCategory = menuItem.getSpinnerStrings();

    public interface AddWordInterface {
        void addWordMethod(String native_lang, String foreign_lang, String Category_name);
    }

    public DialogAddWord() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.final_add_word, container, false);
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        etNAtive = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etAddWordNative);
        etForeign = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etAddWordForeign);
        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spAddWord);
        btnSave = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnaddword);
        btnDone = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelAddWord);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), R.layout.custom_spinner_item, arrayList4spinnerCategory);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String native_lang = etNAtive.getText().toString();
                String foreign_lang = etForeign.getText().toString();
                String category_name = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                addWordInterface.addWordMethod(native_lang, foreign_lang, category_name);
                etForeign.getText().clear();
                etNAtive.getText().clear();
            }
        });
        btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        int dialogWidth = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int dialogHeight = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            Activity activity = (Activity) context;
            addWordInterface = (AddWordInterface) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                + " must implement SellFragmentListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        arrayList4spinnerCategory.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас код непонятный. В конструктор MenuItem  в параметрах есть context, а создаете вы его createMenu без context

Comment: Создание объекта `MenuItem` у вас без контекста. По идее такой код должен упасть не по NPE, а по отсутствию конструктора вообще не собраться

Comment: @pavlofff скорее всего там создается андроидовский MenuItem.

Comment: @xebeche выложите стектрейс ошибки

Comment: Где вообще вызывается getSpinnerStrings() ?

Comment: @pavel163, В классе MenuItem есть еще констуктор без параметров. В createMenu я создаю обьект без параметров.

Comment: @pavlofff, getSpinnerStrings() вызывается в DialogFragment, в котором arraylist передается  для списка в спиннере.

Comment: И в этом фрагменте в качестве контекста что вы передаете? Зачем вообще приводить код активити, который не связан с проблемой вместо кода фрагмента, где вызвается метод с проблемой.

Comment: @pavlofff, добавил требуемый  код

Comment: @pavlofff, Я же в onAttach(Context context) передаю диалогу контекст? или я не так понимаю

Comment: Причем здесь контекст в диалоге и контекст нужный в другом классе? Это как спрашивать, почему у вас дома нет воды, а в соседнем доме же она есть, вот вам и надо протянуть трубу из то6о дома в ваш - передать контекст в другой класс. Напишите, что я вам в комментарии написал. И переименуйте свой класс не как компоненты андроид. Из за этого тоже могут быть проблемы, если за импортами не следить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить экземпляр БД вам нужно передать в ваш класс `MenuItem`  `Сontext`. Для этого перенести создание объектов `menuItem` и `arrayList4spinnerCategory` туда, где контекст уже доступен (в метод `onAttach()`, например)

```
public class DialogAddWord extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
 EditText etNAtive,etForeign;
 Spinner spinner;
 Button btnSave,btnDone;
 AddWordInterface addWordInterface;
 MenuItem menuItem;
 ArrayList<String> arrayList4spinnerCategory;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

     menuItem = new MenuItem(context);
     arrayList4spinnerCategory = menuItem.getSpinnerStrings();

    try {
        Activity activity = (Activity)context;
        addWordInterface = (AddWordInterface) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                + " must implement SellFragmentListener");
    }

}
```

Comment: Все работает! Спасибо вам!